# I meet a problem when I use qemu to create a alpha architecture vitual machine

Tags: alpha, qemu

My cmd is as follows:

```
qemu-system-alpha -m 512 -cdrom debian-5010-alpha-netinst.iso -hda alpha.disk -boot d
```

But `qemu` only show me a dialog, print "Hello"
I have use the palcode as bios.

I tried to simply replace the iso to x86 architecture, as follows:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 512 -cdrom ubuntu-18.10-desktop-amd64.iso -hda alpha.disk -boot d
```

everything goes well except the speed is too slow...

I want to figure out where is the problem, I only replace:
`qemu-system-alpha` -> `qemu-system-x86_64`
`debian-5010-alpha-netinst.iso` -> `ubuntu-18.10-desktop-amd64.iso`

At last, I have tried to cross compile source code of qemu and palcode, but that does not help.

Thank you.

Comment: This may be worth asking over as Superuser as well?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to add on following two options: -kernel, -initrd, decompressed vmlinuz and rename it to vmlinux(it is a ELF formate file, but not vmlinuz, which is checked by QEMU), and everything goes well.

My final cmd is:

```
qemu-system-alpha -hda alpha.disk -kernel vmlinux -append ‘console=ttyS0’ -initrd initrd.gz -L pc-bios/ -net nic -net user -drive file=debian-5010-alpha-netinst.iso,if=ide,media=cdrom
```

Comment: But I found that after installing system, the qemu exited. But I don't know how to start my vitual machine...